# JSON viewers don't accept my pattern even after dict going through json.dumps() + json.loads()

Tags: python, json

The result when printing after `a = json.dumps(dicter)` and `print(json.loads(a))` is this:

```
{
  '10432981': {
    'tournament': {
      'name': 'Club Friendly Games',
      'slug': 'club-friendly-games',
      'category': {
        'name': 'World',
        'slug': 'world',
        'sport': {
          'name': 'Football',
          'slug': 'football',
          'id': 1
        },
        'id': 1468,
        'flag': 'international'
      },
      'uniqueTournament': {
        'name': 'Club Friendly Games',
        'slug': 'club-friendly-games',
        'category': {
          'name': 'World',
          'slug': 'world',
          'sport': {
            'name': 'Football',
            'slug': 'football',
            'id': 1
          },
          'id': 1468,
          'flag': 'international'
        },
        'userCount': 0,
        'hasPositionGraph': False,
        'id': 853,
        'hasEventPlayerStatistics': False,
        'displayInverseHomeAwayTeams': False
      },
      'priority': 0,
      'id': 86
    }
  }
}
```

But when trying to read in any json viewer, they warn that the format is incorrect but don't specify where the problem is.

If it doesn't generate any error when converting the dict to JSON and not even when reading it, why do views warn of failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must enclose the strings using double quotes ("). The json.loads returns a  python dictionary, so it is not a valid JSON object. If you want to get valid JSON you can get the string that json.dumps returns.

Comment: So the problem is in the print and not in the data itself (because the data are in double quotes, they already come from the response in the API). What I can't understand is if I'm passing it through ```json.dumps()``` + ```json.loads()``` how will I be able to retrieve double quotes since they are the print generators? What am I missing?

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the additions in the answer, really that was the big structural problem, the print is in loads and not in dumps!

Comment: Also you need lowercase `false` instead of `False`.

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon , I just confirmed that when going through ```json.dumps()``` it already makes this modification, thanks for pointing this out for future views of the question.

Comment: To be more precise, a python dict happens to have very similar syntax to a json file, but you should not rely on that, and there are more differences than just single vs double quotes. If you want json, you should be explicit and that's why you need to use `json.dumps()`.